# Enable to connect my virtual XP machine to my host system machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine

I have created a VM machine in my host system (Windows 7). After creating the VM machine through VM work station, I want to connect this VM machine to my host machine (Windows 7 operating system). The purpose to take data from the host machine.

Comment: What have you tried to do? How did you setup networking on the VM (NAT/passthrough)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a shared folder on Windows 7 and on settings of VM machine, you have shared folder settings.

Here you can map drive.